# Can't boot from USB stick - GNU GRUB opens instead

Tags: boot

While installing Zorin OS, I accidentally turned off my laptop (don't ask how). Now when I try to boot a distribution (Endeavour, Elementary, Hiren's BootCD) from a bootable USB stick, it always opens directly to GNU GRUB version 2.04. As I said, I have tried several distributions and USB sticks, nothing works. On my PC the bootable USB sticks work.

What can I do?

Comment: More info needed. What did you do in BIOS?

Comment: Use diskpart and clear the disk's boot sectors? What research have you done and what have you tried?